# fix problem any user can change password for admin user site using UserCreationForm - django

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-forms

I am new in Django and even after trying thoroughly to find an answer for this question, I couldn't find any.

the problem is any user can change password for admin user site using UserCreationForm , i mean any user can use reset password form he can change my profile in admin page

i don't want allow users change admin profile how to fix this problem ?

models.py :

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    email_confirmed = models.BooleanField(default=False)

@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def update_user_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        Profile.objects.create(user=instance)
        instance.profile.save()
    def __str__(self):
        return self.user
```

urls.py :

```
# Forget Password
path('password-reset/',
     auth_views.PasswordResetView.as_view(
         template_name='user/commons/password-reset/password_reset.html',
         subject_template_name='user/commons/password-reset/password_reset_subject.txt',
         email_template_name='user/commons/password-reset/password_reset_email.html',
         success_url='/login/'
     ),
     name='password_reset'),
```

html page :

```
<form method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_p }}
    <a href="{% url 'home' %}">Back</a>
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Post your code.

Comment: done i edit my code